# "Use of unresolved identifier"

Tags: swift, macos

I started learn Swift 3 but I'm constantly getting error.

Ex:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAlertController'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'UIAlert'

etc.

My code

```
@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "import UIKit"?  (Wait...you have a OSX tag on your question.  Are you writing for Mac or iOS?)

Comment: No such module 'UIKit'
http://prntscr.com/fedb0q

Comment: If you're creating a Mac project, "UI"-stuff doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm developing for macOS

Comment: You tagged the question with `osx`. What OS are you talking about? There is no `UI...` in macOS

Comment: macOS sierra, how can i do

Comment: Look at `NSAlert` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it's worked!

Answer (score 2):

Applications for `OS X` / `macOS` use their own `SDK`'s, which are not the same as `iOS`.

For example, `UIKit` on `iOS` is the equivalent of `AppKit` on `macOS`,  although they are not interchangeable — meaning use libraries, frameworks, SDK's, etc. for the proper platform.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information you gave me.